# How can I throw exception from webservice?

Tags: java, web-services, exception, throw

I am using netbeans to make webservices, I want to make composite webservice using PBEL,
I face a problem in throwing exception in each service,  I define complex Type in the schema of the exception I want to throw, and I make it in WSDL too , but inside the service I don't know how can I throw the exception , Here's the example I am working on :

```
@WebService(serviceName = "CreditCardService", portName = "CreditCardPort", endpointInterface = "org.netbeans.j2ee.wsdl.creditcard.CreditCardPortType", targetNamespace = "http://j2ee.netbeans.org/wsdl/CreditCard", wsdlLocation = "WEB-INF/wsdl/NewWebServiceFromWSDL/CreditCard.wsdl")
public class NewWebServiceFromWSDL implements CreditCardPortType {

public org.netbeans.xml.schema.creditcard.CreditCardResponseType isCreditCardValid(org.netbeans.xml.schema.creditcard.CreditCardType creditCardInfoReq) throws IsCreditCardValidFault {

    List<CreditCardType> creditCards = parseCreditCardsFile();
    CreditCardResponseType creditCardResponseElement = new CreditCardResponseType();

    for (CreditCardType aCreditCard : creditCards) {

        if (creditCardInfoReq.getCreditCardNo() == Long.parseLong(String.valueOf(aCreditCard.getCreditCardNo())) {
            creditCardResponseElement.setValid(true);
            return creditCardResponseElement;
        }
    }
    throws  IsCreditCardValidFault();   //here I want to throw an exception .
}
```

Please can Someone help?

Comment: throw new IsCreditCardValidFault();  does something like this not work?

Comment: It works . Can u please write it in the anwers part:)

Comment: done. Added a bit more detail in case others come into this thread looking for explanation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
throws  IsCreditCardValidFault();   //here I want to throw an exception .
```

needs to be written as

```
throw new IsCreditCardValidFault();
```

`throws` is used in your declaration of the method, where the `throw` keyword is used inside the method to indicate where you will throw the exception.

so as an example

```
try {
   //do something which generates an exception
}catch(Exception e){
   throw e;
}
```

but in your case, you want to initiate the exception yourself so you have to create a new object of that exception type. You will create the exception yourself, so no need to enclose in a try/catch block.

```
throw new IsCreditCardValidFault();
```